# Angular 2 Expression has changed after it was checked. Error with Dynamic Image Src

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a loop that creates a list of events.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let event of venueEvents">
    <div class="event-card">
        <div class="event-image">
            <img src={{getRandomImage()}}>
        </div>
        <div class="event-details">
            <p class="event-title">{{event.name}}</p>
            <p class="event-time">{{event.nextOccursOn | date}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>     
</ng-container>
```

As you can see the image is a dynamic image that is populated with a function.

```
getRandomImage() {
    let baseImageLink = "http://lorempixel.com/640/480/",
        linkKey = {
            '1': 'nature',
            '2': 'sports',
            '3': 'cat',
            '4': 'nightlife',
            '5': 'food'
        },
        randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1);
    return baseImageLink + linkKey[randomNumber];
}
```

This is working as expected, but the console shows an error.

```
 EXCEPTION: Error in ./VenueDetailComponent class VenueDetailComponent - inline template:64:21 caused by: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'http://lorempixel.com/640/480/sports'. Current value: 'http://lorempixel.com/640/480/cat'.
```

This is some temporary function that would never exist in the real application, but I would like to understand the problem and know how it should be solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get that error because you bind a method to a view that returns a different value each time its called

```
 <img src={{getRandomImage()}}>
```

Every time Angular runs change detection `getRandomImage()` is called, and every time a different value is returned.

You should generate the values, store them in an array and than bind to the array instead of the method directly.

Comment: How would I run the function with each iteration to choose a value from the array dynamically?

Comment: As I said, you should run it *before* the iteration and then just access it like `*ngFor="let event of venueEvents; let i=index"><img [src]="images[i]">` or similar.

Comment: I have done that, but how about for 'n' number of iterations.

Comment: `var n = this.venueEvents.length; for(var i = 0; i < n; i++) { this.images.push(...); }`

Comment: Random array for the win. Thank you.